# Win 2008r2 Audit

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, audit, security

I'm trying to turn on auditing but every time i check Success and failure in *Local policy / Computer Conf/Windows settings/security settings/local policies/Audit Policy/ Audit Object access*, it turns on audit for every files/folders. I have just enabled auditing on some folders....

any ideas?

Comment: There is no Support for auditing only "some" Folders. You can handle this with a powershell script to get only the results of the Folder you want. get-help get-eventlog (Powershell cmdlet)

Comment: so it's either audit is enabled for everything or nothing? Then what's the use of putting audit on folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jsut found out how to do that. In a prompt you need to run this command :
auditpol /set /subcategory:"File System" /Success:enable

Then you can specify audit on the folders/files you want.